# How to converge to a bounded real sequence by a sequence of bounded sequences in $l^\infty$ using Banach limits?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, banach-spaces

In the book “A course in functional analysis” by Conway J.B. there is the following exercise question:
[image]

My solution is roughly: For any $\epsilon >0$ we can cover $[-1,1]$ by finitely many $\epsilon$ balls and so we can choose $x_n(i)$ $(where\;  x_n\in  l^{\infty})$ to be the center of the ball of radius $\dfrac{1}{n}$ that contain $x(i)$. Then, clearly, $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x$.

However, this question appeared in the subsection “Banach Limits”. I therefore thought there should be a nicer solution using (probabily existence of) a Banach limit. Is there any solution using Banach limits?

Comment: That's all there is to it, roughly. 
It's most likely in that section because Conway uses this result as a lemma to prove a theorem in that section about Banach limits.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522454/question-on-banach-limits-from-conways-book

Comment: And also, your solution is a very nice argument itself!